# Obligar a dar una explicación por comentario si hay un voto negativo

Tags: característica-nueva

Aveces algunos usuarios votan negativo y el OP aveces en realidad no sabe porque su pregunta no es bien recibida y está consciente de los criterios que tiene el sitio para calificar una pregunta como buena e hizo el esfuerzo porque su pregunta siguiera esos criterios, pero sin embargo recibe votos negativos, una solución al problema es obligar a las personas que votan negativo a comentar para que su voto se haga efectivo.

Comment: Hacer eso violaría el secreto del voto. Como usuarios tenemos la posibilidad de elegir si dejamos un comentario en la pregunta o no. Algunas preguntas pueden mejorarse y tal vez un comentario ayude a que el OP la mejore, pero hay otras preguntas que no mejoran ni con mil comentarios. Las opiniones serán diferentes siempre, pero lo que no se puede hacer es obligar a dejar un comentario por cada voto negativo. Imagina una pregunta que reciba 10 votos negativos. No sólo tendrá 10 comentarios, sino que la mayoría posiblemente sean iguales. Eso no es muy útil tampoco. Saludos

Comment: ¿Cómo les obligarías a escribir un comentario? ¿Que te salga un desplegable cuando le des al botón de -1 y hasta que no escribas algo no te deje? La gente escribiría cosas como "sin comentarios" o "dfsjksdkjfsdljkfh" o cosas más hirientes como "Menuda mierda de respuesta". Además luego los comentarios se pueden borrar. ¿Se borraría también el voto? Creo que lo mejor cuando se recibe un voto negativo es tener un poco de capacidad de autocrítica y ver qué puede haber mal en lo que uno ha escrito, y si se tiene dudas preguntar en meta o en el chat para intentar hacerlo mejor para la siguiente vez

Comment: Se eliminó el usuario O_O

Answer (score 12):

No lo considero adecuado por:

- Dar una explicación del voto implica entrar en un dinámica de discusión sobre si el OP lo considera o no válido
- He visto casos donde el OP no quiere recibir votos negativos y en caso de que ocurra lo toma como una ofensa
- El sistema ya tiene programado un script que evita hagamos uso indebido de ese privilegio, por lo que el voto serial tanto positivo como negativo están regulados
- Se puede caer en controversias sin fin donde tu expones el por qué diste un negativo pero posterior llegamos otros usuarios que no lo consideramos válido y comenzamos a dar positivos y negativos solo considerando los comentarios y no la calidad de la pregunta en si
- Ahora sí quien pregunta o responde considera que no existe razón válida para los negativos siempre existe la opción de reportar con un moderador diamantado quien puede tomar acciones al respecto

Al final la ventaja del voto secreto es que se evita que se tome como *algo personal*, si quien lo emite desea aportar consejos de como mejorar o pedir aclaraciones respecto de la publicación lo puede hacer; sin embargo como en los puntos antes expuestos es mejor que sea opcional para evitar *suposiciones* sobre todo aquellas que generen ideas erróneas del por que